# GitHub displays all code chunks from README.rmd (despite include=FALSE)

Tags: r, github, knitr, r-markdown

I am currently writing a documentation for an [R package hosted on GitHub](https://github.com/environmentalinformatics-marburg/GSODTools). I use `knitr` along with R Markdown to write the README file. Hitting the 'Knit HTML' button in RStudio produces an HTML like I would expect it.

However, pushing README.rmd to GitHub results in what you see in the lower page section when following the above link. For example, the topmost code chunk is declared as follows in the README.rmd file:

````
```{r global_options, include = FALSE}
library(knitr)
options(width = 120)
opts_chunk$set(fig.width = 12, fig.height = 8, fig.path = 'Figs/',
               include = TRUE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE)
```
````

However, the `include = FALSE` statement in the first line of code is simply ignored in this case, and the piece of code that was supposed to be hidden is displayed on the referring GitHub page. In addition, results (e.g. from `plot()`, `head()`) are not visualized although `opts_chunk$set(..., include = TRUE)`.

Did anyone encounter a similar problem and can me help me get my README document displayed correct, i.e. in the way RStudio would handle it, on GitHub?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The readme file you are trying to publish on github should be a plain markdown document i.e., a `.md` file and not the raw `.rmd`. So first you knit the `.rmd` with knitr (within R) as follows:

```
knit(input="readme.rmd", output = "readme.md") #see ?knit for more options
```

That will evaluate the global and chunk options specified in the source `.rmd` and produce a `.md` that's formatted accordingly and which github can render readily.

Comment: Didn't know it was that easy. Thank you (:

Comment: Oh @Shekeine, I forgot to ask: is there a way to directly implement the `knit` statement in my README.rmd file and have it automatically converted when hitting 'Knit HTML', or do I have to execute it manually from the console each time?

Comment: R commands to be executed during `knit()` or when you "hit Knit HTML" can be included in the `.rmd` by enclosing them within double back quotes. However, Writing ``knit(blah blah blah)`` in your `.rmd` might get you into an infinite loop :-), not very sure as I have never tried it: you could, but I don't foresee desirable results. Alternatively, if you use Rstudio, you can ask knitr to "Keep markdown source file" after producing the html. This opt can be enabled in Knitr settings (Little gear next to `knit html` in rstudio) under the `advanced` tab.

Comment: Note that "Keep markdown source file" is available for html output but not for notebook output.

Answer (score 3):

For more information on using an `.Rmd` to generate the `.md` see the `Readme.Rmd` section of http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/release.html

You can also have devtools set up this automatically for your package using `devtools::use_readme_rmd()`.

Comment: Following Hadley's book, I had problem in loading my own package in the Rmd file to demonstrate its use. Indeed, the package is in development, thus not installed on my machine and available to knitr. How to get around this?

Comment: use `devtools::dev_mode()` and install the package. You need to have the package installed to build vignettes.